# Papers on cost of (ir)reproducibility and data loss

Tags: citations, data

I am looking for a study or conceptual/theoretical paper on monetary costs associated with bad data management practices in academia. As "bad" I mean not following [FAIR principles](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201618), lack of archiving, backups, fast networks, and lack of tools to share data.

One and only example I've seen is a comment from DRYAD data system authors "[Data archiving is a good investment](https://www.nature.com/articles/473285a)":

> As an example of how much research is typically published per grant dollar, core grants in population and community ecology from the US National Science Foundation averaged 3–4 publications per $100,000 of grant between 2000 and 2005 [...]. That is, **$400,000 invested in original research resulted in about 16 papers**. [...]
>   Assuming that Dryad has a comparable rate of reuse and collects at least 2,500 data sets annually, an investment of **$400,000 in one year should contribute to more than 1,000 papers** in the next four years — far more than the accepted value for a research dollar.

Here authors claim that good data archiving/management can increase academic "yield" by 10-100X